# Typo3 9 RTE CK_Editor 4 data-attribute in span removed after saving

Tags: addition, custom-data-attribute, rte

I tried to save data-attribute inside a span tag. After saving it`s removed. 
I tried the following configurations in my custom yaml file.

```
processing.allowAttributes: 
 -'span[data]'
processing.allowTags:
 -span
editor.config.extraAllowedContent: "*(*)[data-*]"
```

Nothing helped. 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

To allow saving data attributes to db from RTE fields, you need to ensure that:

1) RTE (CKEditor) will not strip the attributes. This is configurable using `extraAllowedContent`. Below is an example how to allow id attributes additionally to the default rule which allows data attributes and classes.

```
editor:
  config:
    extraAllowedContent:
      - "*(*)[data-*]"
      - "*[id]"
```

If you only need to add data attributes, you don't need the configuration above and can relay on default configuration (from rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml), as data attributes are allowed by default there.

2) then you need to configure PHP side of things - data transformation which happens before data is saved to db. See manual chapter: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Rte/Transformations/Process.html#transformations-process

Below is an example (taken from RTE yaml preset) of allowing `data-abc` attribute in transformation (in addition to attributes which are allowed by default).

```
processing:
  allowAttributes: [class, id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, itemscope, itemtype, itemprop, data-abc]
```

So in your case you were missing proper allowAttributes configuration.